# How do I create input field as text when user clicks on option 'other'?

Tags: jquery, html, select

```
<tr>
    <td colspan=2 style="font-weight: bold;text-align:left;">
            Chief Complaint: <span style="color: Red;">*</span>
        <select name="chief" style="width:160px">
                <option value="0" selected>--Select Complaint--</option>
                <option value="RTA">RTA</option>
                <option value="Blast">Blast</option>
                <option value="Shot">Shot</option>
                <option value="shrapnel">shrapnel</option>
                <option value=" " onclick="" >other</option>
            </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In this code what should I do? When user clicks on 'other' option then there should be a text field to the side of list box. And how can I take that value?

Comment: please help me as early as possible

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use jquery and remove `onclick` from `option`:

```
$("select").on("change",
               function(){
                   if($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "other"){
                       var input = $("<input/>",{
                                       type: "text"
                                   });
                       $("body").append(input);                           
                   }
               });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nqm4D/1/)

Also take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nqm4D/5/) to take the values from textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#chief').change(function() {
      if($('#chief').val() == "others")  {
        $("#show_inp").show();
      }
      });
 });


<tr>
    <td colspan=2 style="font-weight: bold;text-align:left;">
            Chief Complaint: <span style="color: Red;">*</span>
        <input type="text" name="" id="show_inp">
        <select name="chief" id="chief" style="width:160px">
                <option value="0" selected>--Select Complaint--</option>
                <option value="RTA">RTA</option>
                <option value="Blast">Blast</option>
                <option value="Shot">Shot</option>
                <option value="shrapnel">shrapnel</option>
                <option value="others" id="other" onclick="" >other</option>
            </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dJtQj/

Comment: and how can i access textbox value?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kwvAr/1/ check it you can get the value of text box by id or class..